# Action<T> vs anonymous method question

Tags: c#, delegates, action, anonymous-methods

I had a question answered which raised another one, why following does not work? I do not understand it. The compiler says: Cannot convert anonymous method do string. But why?

```
    public List<string> list = new List<string>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        a.IterateObjects(B);
        // why this does not work:
        a.IterateObjects(delegate(string a) { listBox1.Items.Add(a); });
    }
    private void B(string a)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(a);
    }
    public void IterateObjects(Action<string> akce)
    {
        foreach (string a in list)
        {
            akce(a);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some variable confusion. `a` is already declared elsewhere, so change:

```
a.IterateObjects(delegate(string a) { listBox1.Items.Add(a); });
```

to:

```
a.IterateObjects(delegate(string s) { listBox1.Items.Add(s); });
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: My god :D Thank you! Silly me, I was searching what am I missing (just learning this stuff)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because `ListBoxItemCollection.Add` actually returns an integer. So that would be a `Func<string, int>`, not an `Action<string>`.

**EDIT**: Never mind; I guess since you were using a `delegate` statement you would have had to use `return` for it to evaluate as a `Func`-like object.